# Quiver Diagrams in Tex

Tags: diagrams

How can I draw Quiver diagrams (for a specific gauge theory) in Tex like the followings?[image: Quiver Diagrams]

Diagrams have been taken from the following thesis:

[A Pedagogical Introduction to the AGT Conjecture](http://testweb.science.uu.nl/ITF/teaching/2013/R.J.Rodger.pdf)

Any comment or guidance will greatly be appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why don't you show an example of this "quiver" diagram?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you know the package `tikzcd`? This makes such diagrams really easy and gives you the possibility to do fancy coloured stuff (if really necessary).

Comment: Can you at least post an image with the intended result? from a google search there are many possible visual representations. In any case they seem to be graphs with some special interpretation for nodes and edges so you may try to start from the TikZ manual, `\node` and `edge` operations.

Comment: Funny, for me a quiver is a direct graph, typically without loops. In the first instance you should at least try and produce some diagrams yourself rather than asking people to do *everything* for you. You will find similar diagrams in the [tikz](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) manual. For example, see chapters 27 and 29.

Comment: Quiver plots are usually meant for velocity plots of a field so I'm really surprised that these are also called quiver graphs. They look like ordinary graphs to me.

Comment: Have you tried to contact the author of that thesis and ask for the sources?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple solution. It relies on defining the coordinate axes in directions of 30°, 150° and 90°, so that you can easily find coordinates on the honeycomb grid. You then have several parameters influencing the bubble and box shapes. To help with the finding of appropriate coordinates, you can use the `\MarkCoordinates` macro, which also shows the downside (?) of defining the coordinates this way: the coordinates for a point are not unique. Furthermore, you can define a *name* for a coordinate that is put in the end of the current line, which will then have the form *C-name* for easier access when drawing other lines starting here. If no name is specified, the coodinates name will be *C-*, which will be overwritten by any later object with no name given.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\QBubble}[6][]%
% [1]: content (optional)
%  2 : start coordinate
%  3 : direction -> relative to start
%  4 : line options
%  5 : node options 
%  6 : end point coordinate name
{ \draw[#4] (#2) -- node[semithick, circle, draw=black, solid, fill=white, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=5mm, #5] {#1} ++ (#3) coordinate (C-#6);
}

\newcommand{\QBox}[6][]%
% [1]: content (optional)
%  2 : start coordinate
%  3 : direction -> relative to start
%  4 : line options
%  5 : node options 
%  6 : end point coordinate name
{ \draw[#4] (#2) -- node[sloped, pos=1, semithick, rectangle, draw=black, solid, fill=white, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=5mm, #5] {#1} ++ ($1/2*(#3)$)  coordinate (C-#6);
}

\newcommand{\MarkCoordinates}[3]%
% 1 : x-range
% 2 : y-range
% 3 : z range
{ \foreach \x in {#1}
    {   \foreach \y in {#2}
        {   \foreach \z in {#3}
            {   \node[gray,font=\tiny,shift={(0,0,\z*0.2)}] at (\x,\y,\z) {(\x,\y,\z)};
            }
        }
    }
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
[   x = {(30:1cm)},
    y = {(150:1cm)},
    z = {(90:1cm)},
    scale=1.25,
]
    \MarkCoordinates{0,...,2}{0,...,2}{0,...,2}
    \QBubble{0,0,0}{1,0,0}{blue, thick}{draw=red}{a}
    \QBubble{C-a}{0,0,1}{densely dotted}{}{x2R}
    \QBubble[$\gamma$]{C-x2R}{0,1,0}{ultra thick}{}{Bla}
    \QBox[4]{C-a}{0,-1,0}{}{}{}
    \QBox[Q]{C-x2R}{1,0,0}{red}{draw=green}{}
    \QBox[$\sum$]{0,0,0}{0,1,0}{gray}{draw=gray}{}

    \draw[-latex] (0,2.5,3.5) -- ++ (1,0,0) node[pos=1.2] {$+x$};
    \draw[-latex] (0,2.5,3.5) -- ++ (-1,0,0) node[pos=1.2] {$-x$};
    \draw[-latex] (0,2.5,3.5) -- ++ (0,1,0) node[pos=1.2] {$+y$};
    \draw[-latex] (0,2.5,3.5) -- ++ (0,-1,0) node[pos=1.2] {$-y$};
    \draw[-latex] (0,2.5,3.5) -- ++ (0,0,1) node[pos=1.2] {$+z$};
    \draw[-latex] (0,2.5,3.5) -- ++ (0,0,-1) node[pos=1.2] {$-z$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]